Compare every other column in a file to one column in another file (including non matching records)
I have file1.gz That looks like
NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4017    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4019    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC   

I need to compare $1,$2, plus every letter in every other column in file1 ($1,$2,letter 1 of $4, then $1,$2, letter 2 of $4, then $1,$2, letter 1 of $6, then $1,$2, letter 2 of $6, and so on) to $1,$2,$5 of file2 bellow.
 chromo  position        major   minor   ref     anc     knownEM nInd
NC_044998.1     4013    T       G       T       T       0.000000        1
NC_044998.1     4016    G       T       G       G       0.000000        1
NC_044998.1     4018    T       A       T       T       0.000000        1
NC_044998.1     4019    G       A       G       G       0.000000        1
NC_044998.1     3760    G       A       G       G       0.000000        1

If there's a match add "ref" else add "dev". The result of each comparison can be appended to the last column, as in the output bellow.
    NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  ref ref dev dev ref ref ref ref ref ref  
    NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT  dev dev dev dev dev dev ref ref dev dev        
    NC_044998.1     4017    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev    
    NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  ref ref ref dev ref ref ref ref ref ref     
    NC_044998.1     4019    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC  dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev 

I'm trying to use a solution for a similar problem I had Compare every other column in a file to one column in another file
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
FNR == NR {
   map[$1,$2] = $5
   next
}
($1,$2) in map {
   for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=2)
      for (j=1; j<=2; ++j)
         $0 = $0 " " (substr($i,j,1) == map[$1,$2] ? "ref" : "dev")
} 1' file2 file1

but this times I want for the records present in file 1 but not file 2 to be printed as "dev", instead of being left empty.

regarding file2: can a specific pair of chromo + position occur more than once in the file but with different values for ref? for example, could both NC_044998.1 / 4013 / T and NC_044998.1 / 4013 / G occur in file2?

Please [edit] your question to include your attempt to solve your problem. The code in your question is just a copy/paste of the answer you got to your previous question, it shows no effort by you to try to enhance it for your current problem and I'd hope given how many awk questions you've asked and had answered over the past few years that you'd have learned enough to be able to make an attempt at this.

Suggest following changes:

store file2 items as 3-part index in array
force evaluation of all even numbered fields (starting with field #4) in file1 (regardless of whether or not there's a match for an array index - as in OP's current code)

Modifying OP's current code:
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR==NR { cpr[$1,$2,$5]; next }            # "c"hromo "p"osition "r"ef
        { lastcol = ""
          for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=2)
              for (j=1; j<=2; ++j)
                  lastcol = lastcol " " ( ($1,$2,substr($i,j,1)) in cpr ? "ref" : "dev" )
          print $0 lastcol
        } 
' file2 file1

This generates:
NC_044998.1     4013    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  ref ref dev dev ref ref ref ref ref ref  
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT  dev dev dev dev dev dev ref ref dev dev        
NC_044998.1     4017    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev    
NC_044998.1     4018    0       TT      0       TA      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  ref ref ref dev ref ref ref ref ref ref     
NC_044998.1     4019    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC  dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev dev 


You can just make the loop unconditional:
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
FNR == NR {
   map[$1,$2] = $5
   next
}
{
   for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=2)
      for (j=1; j<=2; ++j)
         $0 = $0 " " (substr($i,j,1) == map[$1,$2] ? "ref" : "dev")
} 1' file2 file1

Or to avoid autovivification, and reduce the amount of lookups:
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
FNR == NR {
   map[$1,$2] = $5
   next
}
{
   val = ($1,$2) in map ? map[$1,$2] : ""
   for (i=4; i<=NF; i+=2)
      for (j=1; j<=2; ++j)
         $0 = $0 " " (val && substr($i,j,1) == val ? "ref" : "dev")
} 1' file2 file1


If $1,$2 are repeated in file2 this will not work as expected.

@RenaudPacalet if $1,$2 in file2 are repeated, there is no issue unless $5 differs. But the original (supposedly-working) code assumes that$5 is unique for a given $1,$2 pair (or map[$1,$2]=$5 makes no sense).
